# insert json array into mongodb php

Tags: php, mongodb

I converted my old mysql data into csv, then csv to json.
Now I want to insert in my mongodb

here's the json

```js
       $json =[
   ["(2"," 'Kea'"," 'Sand'"," 'kea.sand@gmail.com'"," '2013-07-28'"," ''"," '0000-00-00'"," 0)",0];
```

there are hundreds of these records.

Here's what I've tried

```
 $j=json_decode($json,true);
 foreach($j as row){
     $todo=array('email'=>$row[4], //email address row
                 'name'=>$row[2],
     );
     $collection->insert($todo);
 }
```

In theory I thought it would work but negative. All the other codes of tried have been variations of for each. 
How can I do this right?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that what you have generated is not valid JSON and that is why it does not parse. You need something like:

```js
{ "name": "Kea", "email": "kea.sand@gmail.com" }
```

Probably your best option is to go back to your csv file and use [mongoimport](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/) in order to transfer the data. There is an option for [`--type`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/#cmdoption--type) where you can specify csv.

Depending on format of your csv file, if you have emitted a header line with the field names you can use the [`--headerline`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/#cmdoption--headerline) option. If not, then you will need to specify names for your fields via [`--fields`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/#cmdoption--fields).

There are several [usage](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/#usage) examples in the document.

That should allow you import the data and then get to work on the code.

Alternately, then look into ways of forming your JSON properly from a CSV in your code. But there is this utility already.

Comment: Getting nothing but unexpected identifier error when I copy the import code. monogimport -h ds00000.mogolab.com:3344 -d hidle - c (just this 1st part of the code throws the unexpected identifier error.)